# Find conditions on two parameters $c,d>0$ such that the asymptotics of an integral diverges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, proof-writing, asymptotics

Let us start from defining:
$$\underset{c,d}{g(x)}=\displaystyle{\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{x}}z^{c-1}(1-z)^{d-1}dz\tag{1}$$
and:
$$m(y)=\frac{2}{l^2}\displaystyle{\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{y}}\frac{\underset{c,d}{g(x)}}{x^c(1-x)^d}dx\tag{2}$$
with $c,d>0$.

---

---

I would like to find conditions on $c,d>0$ such that:
$$\lim\limits_{y\to0^+}m(y)=\lim\limits_{y\to1^{-}}m(y)=\infty$$

Could you please help me understand how to proceed^?

Comment: In your second eq, what is $y$? You also have $x$ as an input but also $dx$.

Comment: Probably you refer to the penultimate version of the question before my last edit, don't you? Now question should be OK, do you confirm that? @KevinP.Barry

Comment: You can start by expanding $g$ within $m$ to get a double integral to see what simplifications can be made.

Comment: I've tried exactly that approach, but I cannot get to any satisfactory point @KevinP.Barry

Comment: The first eq looks like it can be restated with the incomplete beta function. Not sure if that's helpful. Also notice that $dz$ and $dx$ are negative when $y<\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is merely an attempt to inspire, i was not able to conclude this way.

So i think you can procede in this way.

$$g_{c,d}(x)=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^xz^{c-1}\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}{{d-1}\choose{i}}(-z)^{d-i-1}dz=$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}{{d-1}\choose{i}}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^xz^{c-1}(-z)^{d-i-1}dz=\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}(-1)^{d-i-1}{{d-1}\choose{i}}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^xz^{c+d-i-2}dz$$
where $i \le d-1 \Rightarrow$ $(c+d-i-2)\ge (c-1)>-1$, so there is no "log-case" for the intrgral:
$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^xz^{c+d-i-2}dz=\frac{1}{(c+d-i-1)}\biggl[ z^{(c+d-i-1)} \biggr]_{\frac{1}{2}}^x=\frac{x^{(c+d-i-1)}-\frac{1}{2^{(c+d-i-1)}}}{(c+d-i-1)}$$
so you would have
$$m(y)=\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\frac{(-1)^{d-i-1}{{d-1}\choose{i}}}{(c+d-i-1)}\frac{2}{l^2}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^y\frac{x^{(c+d-i-1)}-\frac{1}{2^{(c+d-i-1)}}}{x^c(1-x)^d}dx$$

Looking at this sum we can arrive at least at a partial conclusion if we consider the sign of the "relevant" term, noting that:

if $y\to 1^-$, $d\ge 1$ gives that the "relevant" integral diverges;

if $y\to 0^+$, $c \ge 1$ gives that the "relevant" integral diverges.

Hope this helps, and also that I made no mistakes.